# Rails, Geocoder, and near

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a slight issue trying to display certain locations based on proximity to a user. In my controller I have this:

```
  if User.find(current_user)
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @locations = Location.near(params[:latitude => @user.latitude, :longitude => @user.longitude], 50, :order => :distance)
  end
```

Users have a latitude and longitude stored. I'm thinking I've not got the right parameters in the Location.near line, but I can't figure out what they should be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: when ever i try to use :order => :distance it show me error `cant convert distance into to_f `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets try re-writing that a bit, current_user should already be set, no need for calling User.find. Then it looks like you can pass lat,long as an array

```
 @locations = Location.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 50, :order => :distance)
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder

http://www.rubygeocoder.com/

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder (check the readme)

Answer (score 2):

You can define the distance that you want search, remember pass the unit, too:

```
@locations = Location.near([current_user.latitude, current_user.longitude], 50, units: :km)
```

Comment: passing the unit in Kilometers was very useful for me. Thanks!